# Complex table rowspan and colspan to show the following image

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td, th{
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The image contains the desired result which should be generated from the code.I have written the following code but somehow the rowspan and colspan are not working together and some other output is generated.
The image is show in the following link :- 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3C84zpiG_wXVEVKU3ZlRFVBd00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/21wd6ae7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created that structure using `rowspan & colspan`, please check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21wd6ae7/1/)

***OR***

Below code:

```css
td{
   padding:10px;
   text-align:center;
   background:#CCC;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tr>
         <td>
             Colspan 1
            </td>
         <td>
             Colspan 1
            </td>
         <td>
             Colspan 1
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             Colspan 1
            </td>
         <td colspan="2">
             Colspan 2
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td rowspan="2">
             Rowspan 2
            </td>
         <td colspan="2">
             Colspan 2
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">         
             Colspan 1 <br> Rowspan 2
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>         
             Colspan 1
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
             Colspan 3 <br> Rowspan 3
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

Comment: Last rowspan, is it necessary?

Comment: which rowspan?? this one Colspan 3 <br> Rowspan 3?